# How do I continuously update the progress of a file upload on the frontend in NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have a form for a multi-file upload on an EJS frontend and I am looking for a way of updating a span with an id of "progressSpan" to show the current progress in % of the file that is being uploaded.

The Frontend form looks like the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
      <label>Select Files</label>
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="realFileinput" multiple>
      <button type="submit" id="submit-upload-btn" class="uploadFormBtns">Start Uploading</button>
      <span id="progressSpan>0%</span>
</form>
```

The function responsible for handling the upload on the backend has been written using multer, altough if something like express-fileupload would be suited better for the progress tracking, then changing it would'nt be a big deal. In the codesnippet below, fileData is an array of JSON objects containing a name and a fileSize, which is handeled by an in this case irrelevant function in the frontend. Depending on the outcome (success/error) it prints the index.ejs file with the according message

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {


upload(req, res, (err) => {
if (err) {
  //render error
  res.render('index', { msg: err, fileData });

} else {

    req.files.forEach(file => {
      
      fileData.push({
        name: file.filename,
        fileSize: convertDataUnit(dir, file.filename)
      });
    });
    res.render("index", { msg: "Upload successful!", fileData });
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Here's a codePen that probably does what you are looking for https://codepen.io/PerfectIsShit/pen/zogMXP  -- If you need the server to send the status of the upload (instead of the frontEnd functions), you can look at the long pulling methods and websockets

Comment: @savageGoat what about the "file_upload_parser.php" on line 15 `ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");` ? I did implement the codepen into my project but the bar doesnt fill up. I have no experience with XMLHttpRequest, but I might assume it has something to do with the code above, since the server runs on nodejs and not php, might be wrong tho